# BOTTOM OVERFLOWED BY Infinity PIXELS?

Tags: firebase, flutter, imagepicker

when i implement this code the display shows Bottom Overflowed by infinity pixels. Anyone knows why? I want that the The Image Picker is in the top left corner.

```
 Scaffold(
              body: Builder(
                builder: (context)=> Container(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children:<Widget> [
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 60.0,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              child: ClipOval(
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  width: 110.0,
                                  height: 110.0,
                                  child:(_image!=null)?Image.file(_image,fit:BoxFit.fill)
                                      :Image.network("https://slcp.lk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/no-profile-photo.png", fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0, right: 40),
                            child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.camera_alt,
                                size: 30.0,
                              ),
                              onPressed: (){
                                getImage();
                              },
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: (){
                          uploadPic(context);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
    ),
```

Here is what it Looks like now [=>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BexR1.png) but i want that the Image Picker is in the top left corner

So I have changed the script the Error is now gone but the Image picker is not display. It should be look like this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIEM4.png)

```
 Scaffold(
              body: Builder(
               builder: (context)=> Container(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children:<Widget> [
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 60.0,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              child: ClipOval(
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  width: 110.0,
                                  height: 110.0,
                                  child:(_image!=null)?Image.file(_image,fit:BoxFit.fill)
                                      :Image.network("https://slcp.lk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/no-profile-photo.png", fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0, right: 40),
                            child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.camera_alt,
                                size: 30.0,
                              ),
                              onPressed: (){
                                getImage();
                              },
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: (){
                          uploadPic(context);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
    ),
          ],
        ),
```

So thats my whole script Maybe that is better to understand.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();



}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  File _image;
  int _currentTabIndex = 0;



  Future getImage() async{
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
      print('Image Path $_image');
    });
  }


  Future uploadPic(BuildContext context)async{
    String fileName=basename(_image.path);
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef=FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask=firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot= await uploadTask.onComplete;

    setState(() {
      print('Profile Picture uploaded');
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Profile Picture Uploaded')));
    });
   }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {



    Future<DocumentSnapshot> getUserInfo()async{
      var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      return await Firestore.instance.collection("SerX").doc(firebaseUser.uid).get();
    }




    final _kTabPages = <Widget>[

      Center(child: Icon(Icons.new_releases, size: 64.0, color: Colors.white)),

      Center(child: Icon(Icons.local_grocery_store, size: 64.0, color: Colors.white)),

      Center(child: Icon(Icons.chat, size: 64.0, color: Colors.white)),


      ListView(
          children: <Widget> [
            Center(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: getUserInfo(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: 1,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            subtitle: Text(snapshot.data.data()["Email"], style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                              fontSize: 10.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                            ),
                            title: Text(snapshot.data.data()["Username"], style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                                fontSize: 25.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),textAlign: TextAlign.right,),
                          );});
                  } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                    return Text("No data");}
                  return Center(
                    child: SpinKitFadingCircle(color: Colors.white, size: 20.0),heightFactor: 29,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Scaffold(
              body: Builder(
                builder: (context)=> Container(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children:<Widget> [
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 60.0,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              child: ClipOval(
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  width: 110.0,
                                  height: 110.0,
                                  child:(_image!=null)?Image.file(_image,fit:BoxFit.fill)
                                      :Image.network("https://slcp.lk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/no-profile-photo.png", fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0, right: 40),
                            child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.camera_alt,
                                size: 30.0,
                              ),
                              onPressed: (){
                                getImage();
                              },
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: (){
                          uploadPic(context);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
    ),
          ],
        ),




      Center(child: Icon(Icons.settings, size: 64.0, color: Colors.white)),

    ];

    final _kBottmonNavBarItems = <BottomNavigationBarItem>[


      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:  Icon(Icons.new_releases, color: Colors.black), activeIcon: Icon(Icons.new_releases,color: Colors.grey) ,title: Text('News',  style: TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xFF000000),
        fontSize: 10.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
      ),),),

      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:  Icon(Icons.local_grocery_store ,color: Colors.black),activeIcon:  Icon(Icons.local_grocery_store,color: Colors.grey), title: Text('Store',  style: TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xFF000000),
        fontSize: 10.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
      ),),
      ),

      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:  Icon(Icons.chat,color: Colors.black), activeIcon:  Icon(Icons.chat,color: Colors.grey), title: Text('Chat',  style: TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xFF000000),
        fontSize: 10.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
      ),),),

      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:  Icon(Icons.supervisor_account,color: Colors.black), activeIcon:  Icon(Icons.supervisor_account,color: Colors.grey), title: Text('Profile',  style: TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xFF000000),
        fontSize: 10.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
      ),),),

      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon:  Icon(Icons.settings,color: Colors.black), activeIcon:  Icon(Icons.settings,color: Colors.grey), title: Text('Settings',  style: TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xFF000000),
        fontSize: 10.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
      ),),),

    ];

    assert(_kTabPages.length == _kBottmonNavBarItems.length);

    final bottomNavBar = BottomNavigationBar(
      items: _kBottmonNavBarItems,
      fixedColor: Colors.black,
      currentIndex: _currentTabIndex,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      onTap: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          _currentTabIndex = index;
        });
      },

    );



    return  Scaffold(

      appBar:  AppBar(

          bottom: PreferredSize(
              child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
                height: 4.0,
              ),
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0)),
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                leading:  Container(),
                title:  Text('Ser X' ,  style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                  fontSize: 35,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                ),),
                titleSpacing: -45,
              ),
              body: _kTabPages[_currentTabIndex],
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavBar,

    );

  }
}
```

Updated

```
Scaffold(
              body: Builder(
                builder: (context)=> Container(
                  height: 200,
                  child: ListView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children:<Widget> [
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 60.0,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              child: ClipOval(
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  width: 110.0,
                                  height: 110.0,
                                  child:(_image!=null)?Image.file(_image,fit:BoxFit.fill)
                                      :Image.network("https://slcp.lk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/no-profile-photo.png", fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0, right: 40),
                            child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.camera_alt,
                                size: 30.0,
                              ),
                              onPressed: (){
                                getImage();
                              },
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: (){
                          uploadPic(context);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
    ),
```

So I uprgaded my Script again

```
ListView(
          children: <Widget> [
            Center(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: getUserInfo(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: 1,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            subtitle: Text(snapshot.data.data()["Email"], style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                              fontSize: 10.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                            ),
                            title: Text(snapshot.data.data()["Username"], style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                                fontSize: 25.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),textAlign: TextAlign.right,),
                          );});
                  } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                    return Text("No data");}
                  return Center(
                    child: SpinKitFadingCircle(color: Colors.white, size: 20.0),heightFactor: 29,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Scaffold(
              body: Builder(
                builder: (context)=> Container(
                  height: 100,
                  child: ListView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children:<Widget> [
                          Container(
                            padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, top: 0),
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 60.0,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              child: ClipOval(
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  width: 110.0,
                                  height: 110.0,
                                  child:(_image!=null)?Image.file(_image,fit:BoxFit.fill)
                                      :Image.network("https://slcp.lk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/no-profile-photo.png", fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0, right: 40),
                            child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.camera_alt,
                                size: 30.0,
                              ),
                              onPressed: (){
                                getImage();
                              },
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: (){
                          uploadPic(context);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
    ),
          ],
        ),
```

Solved Code!

```
 ListView(
        children: <Widget> [
          Center(
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getUserInfo(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: 1,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          subtitle: Text(snapshot.data.data()["Email"], style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                            fontSize: 10.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                          ),
                          title: Text(snapshot.data.data()["Username"], style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                              fontSize: 25.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),textAlign: TextAlign.right,),
                        );});
                } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                  return Text("No data");}
                return Center(
                  child: SpinKitFadingCircle(color: Colors.white, size: 20.0),heightFactor: 29,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children:<Widget> [
              Container(
                padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, top: 0),
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 60.0,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: ClipOval(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 110.0,
                      height: 110.0,
                      child:(_image!=null)?Image.file(_image,fit:BoxFit.fill)
                          :Image.network("https://slcp.lk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/no-profile-photo.png", fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.camera_alt,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 30.0,
                  ),
                  onPressed: (){
                    getImage();
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: (){
              uploadPic(context);
            },
          ),
        ],

      ),
```

Comment: Could you show an image or sketch what do you want?

Comment: I have now upload a Picture what it should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why error?**
Bottom is overflowed by infinity pixel because by default column take all the height available on the screen and if you give height to its child elements like by adding font size,padding,margin etc to its children then at some point its child does not fit into column and give this error.
**Solution:**
Use **ListView** because its adding scroll functionality but in this case you give specific height to column so column know the area in which it scroll.

To Align element to **top left** in column or row : use **crossAxisAlignment.start**

Comment: Overflowed error is gone thanks but it Display not the Profil Picture Function in the top left.

Comment: Row mainAxisAlignment is left to right and you set it to center then how you expect to profile picture to be left.change MainAxisAlignment of row to MainAxisAlignment.start

Comment: When i do this the console give me this error : RenderIndexedSemantics object was given an infinite size during layout.

Comment: update the code in post as you mentioned your overflowed error is gone so we analyze your code properly.And also upload error log

Comment: So i have uploaded the whole script.

Comment: also replace column in scaffold with listview  becuase inside column, you give a child row and that row take infinity heigt.Try it maybe it works

Comment: I replaced Column with Listview but the profile Picture not Display on my screen.

Comment: Because you did not give specific height to column try it {
Container(
height: 200,
ListViiew(),
}

Comment: wrap listview in container and give specific height(available) to container,so listview know the area in which it scroll by default listview does not know the available area in which it scroll

Comment: I uploaded my script again and changed it  can you pls look at that. Because it not Display again

Comment: In align widget you give alignment.center,this force picture to be displayed on center,remove this

Comment: I removed this Nothing happens :( Btw it Display Nothing from my Profil picture

Comment: So I posted the Question again.

Comment: bro i got one more solution remove only align widget in row and replace with container and add padding so set left padding of container to 0

Comment: bro again same issue :( i uploaded my edited script

Comment: I have found out what the Problem was anyway thanks for helping

Comment: can you tell me how you solve this problem i am also learning flutter

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the column with a `SingleChildScrollView.`

This overflow occured because the column is taking all available space that is the height of the screen in this case.